# Custom event fired it's caching by the same event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a custom event called `foo` and I had register this two listeners in my code

```
var $selector1 = $('#foocontainer .item');
var $selector2 = $('#blah .item');

$(document).on('foo',$selector1, 
    function(){ console.log('blah');
 });
$(document).on('foo',$selector2, 
   function(){ alert('testing 123...'); 
});
```

As you can see the selectors and the event handlers are different, why when I fired the event the event handler catching it's always the first one?. I supose that each selector have their event handler and by consequence shouldn't mixed up.

I'm fired the event with the function trigger

```
$('.item').click(function(){
    $(this).trigger('foo');
});
```

Do I missing something?

Comment: Here is a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/nF943/

Comment: Is `#blah .item` a descendent of `#foocontainer .item` (or vice versa)? Remember, events bubble. You also haven't posted enough code for us to reproduce/solve (or interpret, really) the problem.

Comment: also have no idea what `this` is in your trigger selector

Comment: ok, @Adam so I made a few changes in the question, must for tried to represent how it's called the trigger function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) expects a string selector, your are passing it a jQuery object:

```
$(document).on('foo', $selector1, 
    function(){ console.log('blah');
 });
```

You can fix this by changing your on statements to something like:

```
$(document).on('foo', "#d1", function () {
   // do something
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nF943/5/)